# ¿Por qué mi función no llega al retornar el else?

Tags: javascript

La función retorna correctamente la condición inicial, es decir `medallaSegunPuesto(1)`, `medallaSegunPuesto(1)` y `medallaSegunPuesto(1)`, pero no funciona cuando deberia retornar a partir del parametro 4, es decir `medallaSegunPuesto(45);`

```
function medallaSegunPuesto(numero){
    let medallas =["Oro","Plata","Bronce"];
    let loser = "Seguí participando";
    if(1 <= numero <= 3){
        return medallas[(numero-1)];
    } else {
        return loser;
    }
};
```

Comment: Esa condición del if es bastante peculiar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La condición del `if` es incorrecta. Javascript no acepta comparaciones de tres elementos. Lo que estás diciendo en realidad es esto:

```
if ( (1 <= numero) <= 3 ) {
    // primer return
} else {
    // segundo return
}
```

La comparación del paréntesis va a devolver `true` o `false`, dependiendo de lo que valga `numero`.

Luego va a hacer la segunda comparación. Para ello, convertirá el resultado del paréntesis a número, por lo que será `1` si fue `true` o `0` si fue `false`, lo que *siempre* es menor que 3.

Por eso nunca ejecuta el `else`.

La solución:

```
if ( (1 <= numero) && (numero <= 3) ) {
    // primer return
} else {
    // segundo return
}
```